# How can I troubleshoot server overload warnings on my Raspberry Pi 4 Minecraft server using PaperMC?

Tags: raspberry-pi-os, server, minecraft

I opened the minecraft server using raspberrypi 4B model which has 4GB ram
I allocated 3GB to server and used the paperMC to open server.
Also I formatted to rasberrypi OS 64 bit version.

It works well, but sometimes the server connection was lost.
and this is the error message printed on the cmd of raspberrypi.

```
[21:49:07 WARN]: Can't keep up! Is the server overloaded? Running 8763ms or 175 ticks behind
[21:49:54 WARN]: Can't keep up! Is the server overloaded? Running 16587ms or 331 ticks behind
[21:51:22 WARN]: Can't keep up! Is the server overloaded? Running 5621ms or 112 ticks behind
[21:51:59 WARN]: Can't keep up! Is the server overloaded? Running 5089ms or 101 ticks behind
[21:52:39 WARN]: Can't keep up! Is the server overloaded? Running 9787ms or 195 ticks behind
[21:53:21 INFO]: [myname] lost connection: Disconnected
[21:53:31 ERROR]: --- DO NOT REPORT THIS TO PAPER - THIS IS NOT A BUG OR A CRASH  - git-Paper-538 (MC: 1.19.4) ---
[21:53:33 ERROR]: The server has not responded for 10 seconds! Creating thread dump
[21:53:37 ERROR]: ------------------------------
[21:53:41 ERROR]: Server thread dump (Look for plugins here before reporting to Paper!):
> ./start.sh: 줄 1:  1213 죽었음               java -Xms3000M -Xmx3000M -jar paper-1.19.4-538.jar
```

How to find the problem of this?

I want to reopen the server.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try less ram? `java -Xms2G -Xmx2G -jar paper-1.19.4-538.jar'
Also turn down the amount of ram going to gpu by "Running 'sudo raspi-config' from terminal > then select Advanced Options > Memory Split > update the number to 16 > save it & restart the Raspberry Pi."